# Loading condition for analysis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

The problem is shown in Fig. 1.

[image]

**I want to analyze Link 1** by applying load only to link 1. Need to know what is the right approach for loading condition in the software.
**Approach 1 or Approach 2**..?.

[image]

[image]

Please provide reason. I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither approach is correct.

For approach 1, you need to have a counter-clockwise reaction moment $=F*s$ at A for the free body to be in equilibrium.

For approach 2, you need both the counter-clockwise reaction moment $=F*s$ at A, and a force $F$ at B acting to the left for the free body to be in equilibrium.

If you consider both links together as a free body you can see that you need both the counter-clockwise moment at A and the force to the right for the combined links to be in equilibrium.

So,if you modify approach 1 to include the counter-clockwise moment, you can analyze link 1. You will have compressive stress due to the forces and negative bending stress.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1 is correct.**

Consider a free body diagram of Link 2.  The forces on Link 2 must balance.  A force F will therefore exist acting on Link 2 toward the right.

There will be an equal and opposite force acting on Link 1 as you show in Approach 1.

Comment: Doesnt the reaction force at A and horizontal force at B cancel each other out and we are left with only the moment at B.

Comment: @SS4: Yes, there will also be reaction moment at A.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Which approach balances the forces?

Actually neither because at *A* there is going to be a reaction moment which is not accounted for in either approach.

Comment: Since i will be fixing at A all the reaction forces and moments are taken care of.

Comment: @SS4 - but neither free body diagram(s) show a reaction moment and hence are both incorrect. You can't just say fix. in a FBD **you have to show all forces and moments applied**. Those are the rules.

Answer (score 0):

$Fig 1$ cannot remain static. Both **link 1** and **link w** will bend to some extent.

During the dynamic bending phase, point **B** will experience moment and horizontal force. The horizontal force at that time will vary from zero to **F**.

Once static, the horizontal force will equal **F**,  but net moment at **B** will be zero.

Comment: How net moment be equal to zero

Comment: 1) It must, otherwise $link 1$ will keep rotating around axis through **A**. Of course we assume $link 1$ is of zero thickness and there is no additional mechanical support at the junction between $link 1$ and wall. 2) $link 1$ will bend such that its vertical tension will counteract the moment caused by **F**.